# Is tor.stackexchange.com supposed to read-accessible from Tor network?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, website

I keep getting

```
Access Denied

This IP address (...) has been blocked from access to our services.

Reason: Blocked.

Time: Tue, 08 Feb 2022 16:15:56 GMT
```

for rather long time already, even switching circuits repeatedly does not work.

It is rather typical that user contributions are blocked from Tor, but I expect the content to be at least viewable.

Is there maybe some official StackExchange policy or blog post about Tor access? Is it blocked indefinitely or temporarily?

Comment: Related: https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385/dot-onion-address-for-our-community.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with you, but there's a WAF fire-up for a Tor exit node, that happens everywhere - and - it's sort of normal: some malicious traffic could be sent before from that particular exit node or just too much requests per a fraction of time. But we need a Tor hidden service for full access to Tor.StackExchange for sure!

Comment: Is it a long-term DoS attack over Tor to warrant such a long-term block even for reading public content? Typical Tor abuse results in shorter bans.

Comment: Bans are **totally** and **solemnly** up to the WAF setup at the very service you're trying to reach. It's a poor skill result, IMHO - *just* add a hidden service for your resource and use a HTTP redirect in case of Tor exit node, IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

StackExchange seems to be accessible from Tor now. Also I see public update about the issue:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376060/update-on-the-ongoing-ddos-attacks-and-blocking-tor-exit-nodes

According to the post, StackExchange is indeed supposed to be accessible from Tor network, except of when some attack occurs.

> The decision to block Tor exit nodes did not come lightly

> We did not target, nor set out to block all traffic from Tor

The ban was long because of the attack was long.